# Playwright-docker loading browser extension

Tags: playwright, browser-extension

I am new to using Playwright, and I'm trying to load our Chrome extension in a Docker container. Locally, I was able to load the extension successfully, but when I run the same code in the Docker container, I encounter a pop-up message saying that the extension is not installed.

I understand that extensions cannot be installed in incognito tabs (which is what Playwright uses), and when I click on "Install" in the pop-up, it shows that installation is not possible.

Is there any workaround or configuration I can use to make the extension work with Playwright in the Docker container?

```
async function launchBrowserWithExtension() {
  const pathToExtension = '/Users/...';
  const userDataDir = '/Users/...';

  // Launch the browser with the extension loaded
  const browser = await chromium.launchPersistentContext(userDataDir, {
    headless: false,
    args: [
     `--headless=new`, //New way to run extension on headlessmode
      `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
      `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`,
      '--no-first-run',
    ],
  });

  return browser;
}
```